# Brightness suddenly maxes out on lowest two steps (NVIDIA driver 525)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, gpu

The following attachment should clarify what I mean. Brightness rules normally until the lowest two portions of the slider, then it suddenly maxes the brightness. The problem started occuring ever since updating from 515 to 525.

[image]

I would prefer not to downgrade back to 515, since 525 made my system more fluid.

Btw: my laptop is a Lenovo Legion 5 17" with Ryzen 7 4800h and a 1660ti.